# create UITableViewCell from uicollectionView choice

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, ipad

I'm actually doing an app which loads contents to a UICollectionView as the user selects 1 it should create a UITableViewCell and add it to an UITableView on the right but I keep getting errors

In the ViewDidLoad I register the Nib (where cart @IBOutlet var cart: UITableView? and is connected to Storyboard)

```
 cart!.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "cartCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

When the cell is selected I add the object to an array and refresh the table

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row < serviceList.count {
        let service:Service = serviceList[indexPath.row]

        cartOrder.append(service)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            self.cart!.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

But when the table is filling its content I get an error at the declaration of cell

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cartCell
    let serv = cartOrder[indexPath.row]

    cell.lblName.text = serv.name
    cell.lblDescription.text = serv.description
    cell.imgService.image = UIImage(named: "star")

    return cell
}
```

The error Im getting is

```
2016-02-19 16:41:33.375 trackMyDevice_1.0[43188:5851609] ***
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', 
 reason: '[<NSObject 0x7fe645009320> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
 this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imgService.'
```

Any help is well appreciated

Comment: 2016-02-19 16:41:33.375 trackMyDevice_1.0[43188:5851609] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x7fe645009320> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imgService.'

Comment: View in xib is not of cartCell class. Just click on top view in interface builder and set class to cartCell

Comment: had already done that the error was something else, I actually corrected it. I'll post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I register the Nib

So you have a nib called *cartCell.xib*, is that right? And that's what you are registering here:

```
cart!.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "cartCell", bundle: nil), 
    forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Later you load that nib to get a cell, by saying this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", 
    forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cartCell
```

Now, that line makes an explicit claim that the cell loaded from the nib will be a cartCell. But the problem is that the top-level object in that nib, *cartCell.xib*, is in fact *not* a cartCell. It isn't *any* kind of UITableViewCell. It is an NSObject! And thus, you crash with a complaint that this thing is an NSObject:

```
<NSObject 0x7fe645009320> ... this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imgService
```